# Redux Reselect is not fetching the data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I used Redux and reselect, but I couldn't fetch data by `connect` function from server. but if I use `useSelector` and `useEffect` hooks. it will work correctly and fetching data successfully.
but I need want to use `connect` function instead of `useSelector`.
I worked project in https://codesandbox.io and the source code is in below link.

[source code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-lichterman-bt6vd?file=/src/store/user.js)

 sample code is here.
Thanks a lot

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import api from "./api";
const initialUser = localStorage.getItem("user")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
  : null;

// Slice
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: initialUser,
    users: [],
    isLoading: false,
    error: false
  },
  reducers: {
    startLoading: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
    hasError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(action.payload));
    },
    logoutSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.user = null;
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
    },
    usersSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
    getUsers: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
    }
  }
});
export default slice.reducer;
// Actions
const {
  loginSuccess,
  logoutSuccess,
  usersSuccess,
  startLoading,
  hasError
} = slice.actions;

export const fetchUsers = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startLoading());
  try {
    await api
      .get("/users")
      .then((response) => dispatch(usersSuccess(response.data)));
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch(hasError(e.message));
  }
};
export const login = ({ username, password }) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // const res = await api.post('/api/auth/login/', { username, password })
    dispatch(loginSuccess({ username }));
  } catch (e) {
    return console.error(e.message);
  }
};
export const logout = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // const res = await api.post('/api/auth/logout/')
    return dispatch(logoutSuccess());
  } catch (e) {
    return console.error(e.message);
  }
};

export const selectUsers = (state) => state.user.users;
// App.js
const App = (props) => {
  console.log("users", props.users)
  return <div>sample</div>
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { users: selectUsers(state) };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at redux-api-middleware which provides a much better way of integrating data fetching in a redux workflow